# VLANS trunks doesn't work

Tags: cisco

[image: network]

Switch0 configuration:

```
S0(config)# vlan 10
S0(config-vlan)# name dev
S0(config-vlan)# vlan 20
S0(config-vlan)# name tech
S0(config-vlan)# exit
S0(config)# interface f0/1
S0(config-if)# switchport mode trunk
S0(config-if)# interface f0/5
S0(config-if)# switchport mode trunk
S0(config-if)#interface f0/6
S0(config-if)# switchport mode access
S0(config-if)# switchport access vlan 10
```

Switch1 configuration:

```
S1(config)# vlan 10
S1(config-vlan)# name dev
S1(config-vlan)# vlan 20
S1(config-vlan)# name tech
S1(config)# interface f0/1
S1(config-if)# switchport mode trunk
S1(config-if)# interface f0/18
S1(config-if)# switchport mode access
S1(config-if)# switchport access vlan 20
```

PCA : 192.168.10.2
PCB : 192.168.20.2

Problem: I can't ping the PCB from the PCA. I don't understand what is missing, it's a simple configuration and I followed a tutorial.

Comment: Do you have SVIs for each of the VLANs on the switches? Your hosts are on different networks so you'd need SVIs to route traffic between them.  I don't believe those models of 2960s are layer-3 capable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your setup, PCA and PCB are in separate VLANs. Accordingly, they can't communicate with each other directly.

You can check the VLAN trunk by verifying that both PCs' MAC addresses are visible on both switches (in their separate VLAN, of course).

You need to add a router and make the end nodes use it as a gateway.